# How to do Outline TextField in SwiftUI? (MDCOutlinedTextField)

Tags: swiftui, textview, textfield, outline

I need to do textfield design like this. I tried many way but not found any solutions for it.
And in Google Material not yet for SwiftUI.

[image]

Comment: Would you show code how did you try?

Comment: I used this code https://github.com/EmilioPelaez/FloatingPromptTextField

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. What have your tried? What part of your code does not produce the desired effect?

Answer (score 2):

You may use it with .overlay and .storke:

```
TextField("Enter your email", text: $text)
.overlay(
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
         .stroke(Color(.blue, lineWidth: 2))
```

Comment: I tried this but not same as attached image. it's full border but I need to set same as attached image.

Comment: In that case you can try to use a ZStack and put a small label(give it a Text and a Rectangle) on top of the TextField, and modify its relative location by .offset(x: ,y: ).  I think it may help you with the effect you want.

Comment: And if you want the label only appear while you typing something in TextField, you can use a @FocusState var as a monitor to decide if the label did show up(with a modifier called: .focused($yourFocusStateVar))

Comment: See this link, I want "Outlined text field" type - https://material.io/components/text-fields#outlined-text-field

Comment: I still believe you can make a similar effect with those modifer I mentioned with some animation and FocusState, but if you prefer a more stablished solution you may try this: 
https://swiftobc.com/repo/EmilioPelaez-FloatingPromptTextField-swift-textfield-textview